# Calling python with tensorflow in Anaconda from C#

Tags: c#, python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to call a python script from C#. The problem is, this python script uses tensorflow, which I installed using Anaconda.

Normally, I have to call `activate [my_environment_name]`, then `python my_script.py` and try to get the result from stdout. And I may want to call this script in this environment again instead of activating it everytime I call this script.

Anyone knows how exactly can I do this from C#? Thanks.

Comment: here is example how to call into tensorflow from C# using pythonnet: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/473